# Find points betwenn two points?

Tags: coronasdk

In my game I draw the line using two points. I want to calculate the points between the line. Please give any formula for finding points between the two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your two points are `A` and `B` then

> r(t) = A + t(B - A) , where t is greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1

is the equation of the line joining `A` to `B`, and consequently allows you to find any point lying on the line between them (by using an appropriate value for t).

Does this help??